# Цвет вершины у ломанной

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть ли возможность изменить цвет/форму вершины у **Polyline** ломаной линии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вершина ломаной не является отдельной составной частью геометрии, поэтому настраивать её нельзя. Но в режиме рисования/редактирования линии у неё появляются отдельные вершины и промежуточные точки, которые можно кастомизировать, в частности [задать им `layout`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.LineString-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.edgeLayout):

```
vertexLayout: 'default#image',
vertexIconImageHref: 'images/button3.png',
vertexIconImageSize: [16, 16],
vertexIconImageOffset: [-8, -8],
```

[Вот пример в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/editor_icon_layout?from=SO)